Accessing specific index out of N indices within multiple files with varying length of tensors
Suppose that I have 20000 files, each has a tensor with a different length. the total length in all files is 3814139. I need to access the file that contains the specified index. So for example, if (tensor length of file_0 is 320, tensor length of file_1 is 1036, tensor length of file_2 is 458, ......., tensor length of file_19000 is 241), to access index >319 and < 1356 it's located in file_1.
What is the fastest way to access indices for huge length of indices within multiple files, in such fashion?

You can do something like this:
# lengths of individual files in order
file_lengths = torch.tensor([320, 1036, 458])

# cumulative lengths
cum_lengths = torch.cumsum(file_lengths, 0)
print(cum_lengths)
> tensor([ 320, 1356, 1814])

# values we want to map to files
queries = torch.tensor([300, 320, 500, 1700])

# index values of files
file_idxs = torch.searchsorted(cum_lengths, queries, right=True)
print(file_idxs)
> tensor([0, 1, 1, 2])

Play around with the values, you can see how searchsorted correctly maps query values to the index of the correct associated file.
Make sure to use right=True to get the behavior you want. If you run the above code with right=False, it will map 320 to document 0 instead of document 1.
